# How can I be totally invisible to Facebook?

Tags: browser, privacy, facebook

I don't trust Facebook. I deleted my account, but I don't want them getting information from me from other sites, either; for instance, those with "Like" buttons cause my browser to request assets from their site, which tells them my IP address and other information that they could use to identify me. By logging this, they could know a lot about my activities.

I'm thinking I could set my browser not to request images from their site, but I'm not sure if that's enough.

**What browser settings or other software can make me completely invisible to Facebook as I browse the web?**

Comment: If you recewntly delted your self it can take upto 60 days before you get removed form search engine indexing. By the way.. did you know that even you pressed delete.. all your information is still stored on the servers for statistical information. You can request those details via your lawyer using the privacy act, and they will send you a CD.. but when you signed up you agreed to let facebook keep data about you, and you cant force them to delete it.. owned.

Comment: @ppumkin: Depends; EU citizens can. EU law trumps Facebook terms.

Comment: @MSalters ohh yea.. you are right.. thanks for adding that

Answer (score 8):

You can block all facebook trackers using [Ghostery](http://www.ghostery.com/) (works *best* in firefox) .
If you prefer to load Facebook plugins anonymously use [Priv3](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/priv3/) (another firefox extension)

Comment: Nice tools.. Never knew stuff like that existed

Answer (score 4):

You can also modify your hosts file to point www.facebook.com (and another facebook's hostnames) to 127.0.0.1.

Comment: Clever. For users who don't understand this, it would mean that when my computer tries to load an image or other resource from Facebook's site, it would look for it on its own network address, not find the resource, and give up. Facebook would never know about the request.

Answer (score 1):

## A. Firewall Blacklist.

I find it is always useful to have a Firewall Blacklist list in place so that I can easily add sites to it (or even automated entries if there was a need).  Much for the same reasons as you.  I get that feeling whenever I look at the logs.

---

- This also allows you to cut traffic both **going to** and **coming from** Facebook.
- This involves no third-party apps and terminates the requests.  Following good security practice (OpenBSD-flavor), a process (in this case connection request) that is "mis-behaving" should be terminated.
- Also, there is a grey line between all the third-party sites that might be associated with it or some other social media site.  No need to limit yourself to Facebook.
- This solution offers you fine-grained control.  Which is appropriate for someone with specific needs.
- This is also a solution that is secure and should not change over time as it is not a hack or part or an unusual configuration.  It is what you would expect, where you would expect it.
- This solution in itself is very portable and very forward-compatible.  All you need is the list.

---

## A. Use an enterprise-style blacklist.

Let other people find all the redundant addresses and make updates...

Blocking Facebook is a common thing to do in enterprises.  You can find a number of other interesting categories such as "spyware" that would be useful without limiting the information you actually want.

### - You can augment your blacklist with categories from a cost-free, updated public blacklist such as the ones at [shallalist.de](http://www.shallalist.de/categories.html).

( Click "Download" next to "md5" )